# Steps to follow to install ubuntu 13.04 on an ultrabook

Tags: installation, 13.04, ssd, ultrabook

How exactly should I install ubuntu on my ultrabook so that I can use all my ultrabook hardware at its best? Since, I am new to Ubuntu, it will be really helpful if you can elaborate each step.

My laptop is Dell inspiron 14z ultrabook. I want to install solely ubuntu on it.

Comment: Do you have an OS installed?

Comment: Are you trying to dual-boot? What is your PC model and manufacturer?

Comment: Please don't cross-post on SE sites: http://superuser.com/questions/627541/how-to-install-ubuntu-13-04-on-an-ultrabook